# I can't figure out where is my mistake, can anyone help me with it? (Python)

Tags: python, xcode, list, variables, rename

```
# 1. Create a list of all of the names
name = ["kaki", "helen", "makir", "pallu"]

print("My cousins are" + name+ "but helen is different than them.")
```

**Error:**

```
 ----- print("My cousins are" + name+ "but helen is different than them.")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str. -----
```

Comment: you can't put list type into your string

Comment: Your mistake is as exactly as reported in the error message, your code is adding (`+`) a `list` `[...]` to a `str` `"My cousins are"`, and that is not possible because they are different types.

Comment: `print("My cousins are " + ','.join(name)+ " but helen is different than them.") ` Or `print("My cousins are " + str(name)[1:-1]+ " but helen is different than them.")`
You are concatenating list to string.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print("My cousins are " + str(name) + " but helen is different than them.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate with +, simply change to comma:

```
name = ["kaki", "helen", "makir", "pallu"]

print("My cousins are", name, "but helen is different than them.")
```

Here is the output:

```
My cousins are ['kaki', 'helen', 'makir', 'pallu'] but helen is different than them.
```